# cannot receive the broadcast sent by myself

Tags: android

I have sent a broadcast here:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("com.example.administrator.broadcasttest.MY_BROADCAST");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have send a broadcast just now.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
}
```

But i can't receive it in my broadcast receiver:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "received in MyBroadcastReceiver",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.administrator.broadcasttest">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.administrator.broadcasttest.MY_BROADCAST"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

In addition, my andriod version is 7.1.1, and my API version is 26.
I have tried many ways to solve it, but none worked.
I am searching for a long time to no avail

Please help or try to give me some ideas about how to achieve this.Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Are you using two different files for MA and BR?

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks a lot. I have modified it.

Comment: @Toro Yes. My broadcast receiver is declared in another java file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have more than one public class in a java file.  Move your broadcast receiver class into a separate file.

Comment: I could not commit more than 2 pics at first, so i put them into a pic. I have modified my question with code instead of pics. In fact, they are in different java file.

Answer (score 0):

I usually register receivers via XML AND code.

Try to register it:

```
BroadcastReceiver whatever = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
registerReceiver(whatever, intentFilter); 
//Intentfilter is the intent you get in MyBroadcastReceiver
```

Hope it helps.

EDIT: DO NOT FORGET TO UNREGISTER IT:

```
unregisterReceiver(whatever);
```

Comment: I know i can register receivers dynamically like you, but when it comes to register via <reveiver>, it doesn't work. But thank you for your advice.